# When to use “tomato” and when to use “toma­toes”?

Tags: grammaticality, grammatical-number, articles, uncountable-nouns, academic-writing

In my sci­en­tific ar­ti­cle manuscript, I used *tomato* to re­fer
to the plant in gen­eral. But af­ter I sent the manuscript to the
El­se­vier English Cor­rec­tion Ser­vice, they changed all *tomato*
into *toma­toes*. For ex­am­ple this sen­tence:

> This sug­gests that an in­ter­ac­tion among many genes is
> as­so­ci­ated with the mech­a­nism in **toma­toes**.

I am quite con­flicted about this. I only want to re­fer to the
tomato plant in gen­eral, not to em­pha­size dif­fer­ent types of
toma­toes. What is the cor­rect choice in this case? When should I
use *tomato* and when *toma­toes*?

Comment: You cannot say "with the mechanism in tomato." It's ungrammatical.

Comment: If you want to use it generically, it needs to be *the tomato.”

Comment: @tchrist Can you explain more? Why is it incorrect?

Comment: @MDP Because there is no such thing as *tomato* unadorned by some determiner or an inflected plural marker. It is not a substance, a mass noun. It is a count noun in *tomatoes*, and it is an attributive noun in *tomato plant*. So you cannot say *I don't like tomato* as a general thing; it really must be *I don't like tomatoes.*  A native speaker ***might*** be able to rope it into service by asking *Is there any tomato in this? I’m deathly allergic!* But I strongly recommend against attempting it as an ESL learner; it will not come off right. The correction service made the right call here.

Comment: @tchrist That's new to me. I rarely see scientific articles using this plural "tomatoes". I did a search on Nature and the number of articles using "tomato" (as a noun by itself, not an attributive noun) is like 10 times the number of those using "tomatoes". Granted, articles by native English authors seem to use "tomatoes" more often, but it's not hard to find articles by someone from UK or US that use "tomato", like this one: https://www.nature.com/articles/ng.3345.

Comment: @tchrist So is tomatoes a special case/are tomatoes special cases, or should I always use plurals for other things as well, like "I don't like peppers", "I don't like potatoes", "I don't like eggs"?

Comment: There's no special case here. And yes, that's right: Those all have to be in the plural if you don't like them. It's not like mass nouns like wine or pork or salt; those still  don't get used as plurals if you say you don't like them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Formal and precise (i.e. scientific):

> This suggests that an interaction among many genes is associated with
> the mechanism in ***the tomato***.

Here "the tomato" is a species. Substitute "elk":

> This suggests that an interaction among many genes is associated with
> the mechanism in ***the elk***.

However, if you wish to sound more casual - or more colloquial - or more populist - you should go with:

> This suggests that an interaction among many genes is associated with
> the mechanism in ***tomatoes***.

Now, if your goal is to refer to an entity that is *uncountable*, you might consider going with:

> This suggests that an interaction among many genes is associated with
> the mechanism in whatever amount of ***tomato*** you might view as a good sample size.

Comment: So is it the same for all other species, like "the pepper"/"peppers", "the potato"/"potatoes", or is/are (this feels weird) tomatoes the special case? This kind of pluralization seems new to me. I don't remember encountering many scientific articles writing this way.

Comment: Yes, rather, especially if formal is what rocks your boat. There are, however, exceptions, such as "the deer/deer."